# Is chicken treated with sodium triphosphate classified as processed meat?

Tags: nutrition, sodium, preservitives, meat

I've recently seen the data that suggests processed meat is carcinogenic, but I don't know if what I'm buying is the same thing:

http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/cooked-chicken---turkey/sainsburys-cooked-chicken-slices--tikka-160g

The only ingredient that concerns me is the 'Sodium Triphosphate'. Because this ingredient acts as a preservative in a way (it allows the chicken to retain moisture), does that classify it under processed meat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the [WHO](http://www.who.int/features/qa/cancer-red-meat/en/) (the organization that keeps a great list with everything that's definitely carcinogenic):

> "Processed meat refers to meat that has been transformed through
>   salting, curing, fermentation, smoking, or other processes to enhance
>   flavour or improve preservation. Most processed meats contain pork or
>   beef, but processed meats may also contain other red meats, poultry,
>   offal, or meat by-products such as blood."

All the way down there's also a point about the manner of preservation

> "24. Different preservation methods could result in the formation of
>   carcinogens (e.g. N-nitroso compounds), but whether and how much this
>   contributes to the cancer risk is unknown."

The WHO doesn't go this far, but based on compounds in some processed meat that are carcinogenic by itself (smoke and N-nitroso compounds), I'd assume a large part of the carcinogenic risk of processed meat can be explained by the presence of these compounds.

The sodium triphosphate that's in your chicken is technically a preservative. However, sodium triphosphate preserves the meat by retaining water, slowing down the drying process.

Sodium triphosphate itself is [perfectly safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_triphosphate), I think the limits on the quantity that you can add are present mainly because it can be used to cheaply increase the weight of meat/fish. It's also GRAS (generally recognized as safe) by the FDA.

Comment: I couldn't find that last quote on the WHO page, quite interesting. I think I'll be better off cooking from fresh anyway, it's a little cheaper. Thank you.

Comment: WHO is not an institute - they are a UN organisation specialised in health.